# What's the difference between count and length?

Tags: count, scheme

For example in Scheme (count '(1 2 3)) gives 3 and (length '(1 2 3)) also gives 3.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what interpreter you're using. In standard Scheme, only [`length`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_632) is defined. In other interpreters (say, Racket) [`count`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._count%29%29) exists but it's different, it receives a list and a predicate and returns the number of elements in the list that meet the condition.

I don't know in which interpreter `count` is defined as a single-parameter function that returns the length of the list, (In Racket `(count '(1 2 3))` causes an error), but it seems to me that `count` is just an alias for `length` in your interpreter (in other words: they're the same thing) - to be sure, please check the documentation. If I had to choose one, I'd use `length`, which is standard and will work everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

`length` returns the number of elements in a list.

`count` is not a standard procedure mentioned in any of the official Scheme reports (I searched [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/), [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib.html) and [R7RS](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/r7rs.pdf)) so it's not a part of Scheme. In many implementations you will get some sort of error saying that `count` does not exist. This is radically different than the expected result you have in your question but it is the more likely result if you were to test it in 5 Scheme implementations.

There is no reason to use a implementation dependent extension when its result is the same as `length`.

I have tried `(count '(1 2 3))` in stalin (r4rs), scm (r5rs), chicken (r5rs), gambit (r5rs), racket (both r5rs and r6rs), ikarus (r6rs), chibi-scheme (r7rs), gauche/gosh (r7rs). None of them have `count`.

```
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ csi

CHICKEN
(c) 2008-2013, The Chicken Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.8.0.5 (stability/4.8.0) (rev 5bd53ac)
linux-unix-gnu-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
compiled 2013-10-03 on aeryn.xorinia.dim (Darwin)

#;1> (count '(1 2 3))

Error: unbound variable: count

    Call history:

    <syntax>      (count (quote (1 2 3)))
    <syntax>      (quote (1 2 3))
    <syntax>      (##core#quote (1 2 3))
    <eval>    (count (quote (1 2 3)))   <--
#;1> 
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ gsi
Gambit v4.6.9

> (count '(1 2 3))
*** ERROR IN ##raise-unbound-global-exception -- Unbound variable: count
1> 
> 
*** EOF again to exit
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ ikarus
Ikarus Scheme version 0.0.4-rc1+, 64-bit (revision 1870, build 2012-02-21)
Copyright (c) 2006-2009 Abdulaziz Ghuloum

> (count '(1 2 3))
Unhandled exception
 Condition components:
   1. &undefined
   2. &who: eval
   3. &message: "unbound variable"
   4. &irritants: (count)
> 
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ plt-r5rs
Welcome to Racket v6.1.1.
R5RS legacy support loaded
> (count '(1 2 3))
count: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/r5rs-lib/r5rs/run.rkt: [running body]

sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ echo "(import (rnrs))
                                         (display (count '(1 2 3)))" > test.scm
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ plt-r6rs test.scm 
test.scm:2:10: count: unbound identifier in module
  in: count
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/r6rs-lib/r6rs/run.rkt: [running body]

sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ chibi-scheme 
> (count '(1 2 3))
ERROR on line 1: undefined variable: count
>
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ 
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ gosh
gosh> (length '(1 2 3))
3
gosh> (count '(1 2 3))
*** ERROR: unbound variable: count
Stack Trace:
_______________________________________
gosh> 
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ scm
SCM version 5e5, Copyright (C) 1990-2006 Free Software Foundation.
SCM comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `(terms)'.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `(terms)' for details.
;loading /usr/share/slib/require
;done loading /usr/share/slib/require.scm
;loading /usr/share/slib/require
;done loading /usr/share/slib/require.scm
;loading /usr/lib/scm/Link
;done loading /usr/lib/scm/Link.scm
;loading /usr/lib/scm/Transcen
;done loading /usr/lib/scm/Transcen.scm
> (count '(1 2 3))

;ERROR: "/usr/lib/scm/Iedline.scm": unbound variable:  count
; in expression: (count (quote (1 2 3)))
; in top level environment.
;STACK TRACE
1; (#@let ((tail (#@lambda (c) (#@if (#@char? #@c) #@c (#@let* (( ...
2; (count (quote (1 2 3)))

> 
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ echo "(display (count '(1 2 3)))" > test.scm
sylwester@pussycat:/p/n/sylwester$ stalin -On  test.scm
test.scm:1:10:Unbound variable
```